# Should I commit new dependencies that are needed for a feature to the branch the feature is located in or should I commit it to the master branch?

Tags: git, dependencies, branch

So I'm working on this react-native app that needs navigation dependencies in order for the navigation to work. Navigation is of course important for the whole app, but is it mandatory to commit this to the master branch or can I simply commit it to the branch of the feature ('develop' branch)?

Comment: It's upto your team's workflow but I don't see why you would need to commit it into master instead of commiting to your feature branch.

Comment: @satya164  I'm working solo, but I was wondering what the best practice was and if there would be any consequences if I would be working in a team just to be sure. Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 1):

You need to commit it where you need it first: in your `develop` branch.

That branch will be eventually merged to `master`, which means the new dependencies will be merged as well.